# Flutter Autofill login only works on e-mail field and not on password field on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, autofill

There seems to be an issue with the [AutofillGroup](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutofillGroup-class.html) widget when presenting a login form. When selecting the e-mail field and selecting a password, the auto fill works just fine. However, when selecting the password field and choosing the autofill option, it only fills the e-mail field.

I have tried a lot of different configurations, from using `Form` widgets with `TextFormField` and all the different properties that might be related to simple `TextField` widgets as in the below minimum reproducible code.

I also tried using `TextEditingController`, validators, `keyboardType` and `onDisposeAction` on the `AutofillGroup`, all things that should not be related, but at least I made sure that these are not the issue.

Does anyone know more about this issue and whether it can be solved, or whether I should just submit the issue to the Flutter dev team?

```
AutofillGroup(
  child: Column(
    children: const [
      TextField(
        autofillHints: [AutofillHints.email],
      ),
      TextField(
        autofillHints: [AutofillHints.password],
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

**Update**

I have now also tested on Android, there it does work fine, so it is only an iOS issue.

Comment: Hi, try to add controllers to your TextFields

Comment: @Max Thanks! I did try that, it does not solve the issue

Comment: May be something to add to iOS config in runner or permission to store password in Apple dev account ? (Like notifications)

Comment: @Max shouldn't be. Also, it does work when the e-mail field is selected. I think it is a bug in Flutter, I have submitted an issue.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to make it work? I have the same issue as you

Comment: @YoannPicquenot No, it is a bug in Flutter. I have filed [this issue on Github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/91354) and it seems like it is being picked up.

Comment: Yeah i saw there were multiple open issues about this bug!